# Variable Always Ending up to equal 0 C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When running this the var number 10 will always equal 0 after doing the math to find the distance formula. How can I fix this. Thanks in advance

```
        Int32 Number1;
        Int32 Number2;
        Int32 Number3;
        Int32 Number4;
        Int32 Number5;

        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 1st X coordinate");
        Number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 1st Y coordinate");
        Number2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 2nd X coordinate");
        Number3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 2nd Y coordinate");
        Number4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to use the distance or midpoint formula.(Type 0 for distance and 1  for midpoint)");
        Number5 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Int32 Number6 = Number1 - Number3;
        Int32 Number7 = Number6 * Number6;
        Int32 Number8 = Number2 - Number4;
        Int32 Number9 = Number8 * Number8;
        Int32 Number10 = Number6 + Number8;

        if (Number5 == 0)
        {


           Console.Out.Write("Square Root of");
           Console.Out.Write(Number10);



        }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at what the values of `Number6`, `Number8`, `Number1`, `Number3`, `Number2`, and `Number4` are?

Comment: Yes you fill them out as shown when in the readlines.

Comment: Since you're calculating distance between two points, shouldn't you Math.Abs() when you subtract the two points

Comment: 1. It's generally *not* best-practice to use `Int32`, use `int` instead. 2. Those variable names are horrid, it's going to make debugging things extremely unpleasant in the future (and even now). Meaningful variable names are *extremely helpful*. 3. You are doing `Number10 = Number6 + Number8`, which is wrong. It should be `Number10 = Number7 + Number9`. (Note what I said about debugging.) Then you should do your `Math.Sqrt` on it.

Comment: Step through it, inspect the variables.  You'll almost certainly see what the problem is.

Comment: I'm wondering what you see for these values as you're debugging.  Since `Number10` depends on 6 other values, you might want to see where the math errors start.

Comment: You have to debug this code yourself. We can't debug it for you. Here is what you can try: 1) test input, do you get values entered as you think they are? 2) test calculation and logic, do a simple debug output **before** and **after** calculation/logic under question and see if it goes right or wrong...

Comment: int Number6 = Math.Abs(Number1 - Number3); int Number8 = Math.Abs(Number2 - Number4);

Comment: @Shar1er80 `Math.Abs` is unnecessary for Distance Formula.

Answer (score 2):

If you use more sensible variable names and declare the variables at the point of assignment, like so:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 1st X coordinate");
        int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 1st Y coordinate");
        int y1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 2nd X coordinate");
        int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 2nd Y coordinate");
        int y2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to use the distance or midpoint formula.(Type 0 for distance and 1  for midpoint)");
        int forumlaSelection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int dx = x1 - x2;
        int dxSquared = dx * dx;
        int dy = y1 - y2;
        int dySquared = dy * dy;
        int dxPlusDy = dx + dy;

        if (forumlaSelection == 0)
        {
            Console.Out.Write("Square Root of");
            Console.Out.Write(dxPlusDy);
        }
```

Then you might be more likely to see the error.

See that `dxPlusDy`? Looks to me that it should be this instead:

```
int dxSquaredPlusDySquared = dxSquared + dySquared;
```

And your final output should be the square root of that:

```
Console.Out.Write(Math.Sqrt(dxSquaredPlusDySquared));
```

Also, I recommend using `double` rather than `int`:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 1st X coordinate");
        double x1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 1st Y coordinate");
        double y1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 2nd X coordinate");
        double x2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Type in your 2nd Y coordinate");
        double y2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to use the distance or midpodouble formula.(Type 0 for distance and 1  for midpoint)");
        int forumlaSelection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        double dx = x1 - x2;
        double dxSquared = dx * dx;
        double dy = y1 - y2;
        double dySquared = dy * dy;
        double dxSquaredPlusDySquared = dxSquared + dySquared;

        if (forumlaSelection == 0)
        {
            Console.Out.Write("Square Root of");
            Console.Out.Write(Math.Sqrt(dxSquaredPlusDySquared));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I hate to answer questions like this, I feel you could do with a *good* understanding and explanation of some *best-practices* here.

1. Use meaningful variable names. `Number[N]` is **not** meaningful. Making this change causes a discovery of multiple supreme flaws in your logic *immediately*.
2. Don't use `Int32`, it's generally best-practice to use `int` in this case. (Though, for your situation, `double` is more appropriate. But that change is unnecessary.)
3. Your formula is *way* off. (Renaming variables more meaningfully points this out readily.)
4. You don't catch errors with invalid input. You should do *some* attempt at this. The five `while` loops handle this in very small overhead.

[MSDN `Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The following modification fixes *all* of these issues:

```
int x1 = 0;
int y1 = 0;
int x2 = 0;
int y2 = 0;
int option = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Type in your 1st X coordinate");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x1))
    Console.WriteLine("That number is invalid, please try again:");

Console.WriteLine("Type in your 1st Y coordinate");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y1))
    Console.WriteLine("That number is invalid, please try again:");

Console.WriteLine("Type in your 2nd X coordinate");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x2))
    Console.WriteLine("That number is invalid, please try again:");

Console.WriteLine("Type in your 2nd Y coordinate");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y2))
    Console.WriteLine("That number is invalid, please try again:");

Console.WriteLine("Do you want to use the distance or midpoint formula.(Type 0 for distance and 1  for midpoint)");
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out option))
    Console.WriteLine("That number is invalid, please try again:");

int x2x1 = x2 - x1;
int x2x1Squared = x2x1 * x2x1;
int y2y1 = y2 - y1;
int y2y1Squared = y2y1 * y2y1;
int addedSquaredValues = x2x1Squared + y2y1Squared;

if (option == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Distance between ({0},{1}) and ({2},{3}) is {4}", x1, y1, x2, y2, Math.Sqrt(addedSquaredValues));

Console.ReadLine();
```